# How can I read xlsx files into Octave matlab?

Tags: octave

So, I tried to read xlsx file using readtable function in Octave, but it put out a warning message "the 'readtable' function is not yet implemented in Octave". So, what is the way I could possible read xlsx files in Octave?

Comment: Try `xlsread` https://octave.sourceforge.io/io/function/xlsread.html

Comment: @Daniel Ok, now it works, but it throws another error message that the file is not found. It's on my PC, but I need to load the file somewhere in the Octave, but don't know where. Can you help?

Comment: Looks like the path you passed to xlsread is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This will be a very late answer, but I am writing to provide a solution for those who have this problem in the future.

To read .xls files, you need the octave io package because this package includes "xlsread()" function. You can check if you have this package by typing "pkg list" in the octave console. Then, at the beginning of the code, you should write the command "pkg load io". You can now use the xlsread() function.

The outputs of the xls and readtable functions are not exactly the same, so you have to make changes to the output.

[io package:](https://octave.sourceforge.io/io/)
[xlsread function:](https://octave.sourceforge.io/io/function/xlsread.html)